# How much French do I need to know to be in average speaking french user?

Tags: grammaire

I have built a [web application](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Memorize-Sentences) that gives the user sentences so the user can translate them. But it's not because of that I'm here.

I have also [created 19 CSV](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Memorize-Sentences/tree/main/Source/Languages/French-Swedish) files with French sentences and I wonder if these sentences can give me a good basis in the knowledge of French?

Let's pick a CSV file. As you can see, most of these sentences are made up from a dictionary. I just have translated them as best I can to French. My question for you is whether these CSV files can give me a normal speaking French, or do I need to know more? If yes, what? Can I "survive" with such a level in French?

Let me know if I have written something wrong in these French sentences.

[image]

Comment: Proof reading is not permitted on this site; I can assure you that all your sentences are impeccable French except for a "qui" that should be "que".

Comment: @LPH Thank you. What sentence are you talking about?

Comment: @LPH I'm not asking about proof reading. I'm asking about if this kind of french lever OK or is it too basic and poor?

Comment: "Je prend la même chose que lui." —   All these sentences are bound to be useful at one time or another to someone or other but one instance of dining in a restaurant will not require all of them, far from it, while other sentences  that you _will_ need are not in the list.

Comment: @LPH Thank you. I know that there is a small amout of sentences I have chosen. The reason for that is to learn the "reflex" how to pronuce and build structures with them. That's how I learn things. It's quite odd way to do.

Comment: You might be able to ask questions, but what about understanding the answers? It will also be hard to cover in a list all you could drink or eat and a just reading a menu might be tricky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cook books will let you down even after having studied them thoroughly unless they are very comprehensive, and then they take a lot of time to study; however, even if they treat their subject in depth there is a problem  of underlying general knowledge and cook books can't make up for that. There is unfortunately no method for learning a language rapidly. Concerning this question of the "average" speaker I can say this: it depends on what you mean by average French speaker; if you mean enough French to get by in any situation, that amounts to a lot of experience, quite a few years of effort; make no effort and your skills will improve only slowly. I'd say that, if you are a foreigner with no knowledge of French and that you learn the language as you start living in France, combininig self-study or regular study in some school with the everyday drill that is imposed on you by the necessities of life, then you can become that average (foreign) speaker in more or less 5 years' time; it will not, however, give you the skill of a French person considered as an average speaker of French; you will still have a lot of problems.

The list you provide is fine but if you are not familiar with the warp and woof of the language that list will let you down when you find yourself in real interaction with a native; of course they will sometimes manage to get  your meaning but I've witnessed more than one case of situation where the locutors can't get their meaning across and have to leave off their conversation, or worse, when misunderstanding results in errors.

Comment: I have studied basic french. The only problem I have with french is to build structures of that language. I cannot learn the rules by hand. I need to practice it over and over again. Same sentence, every day and every week. Than I can learn it.